# How to merge two 4 channel audio into a single 2 channel output

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I'm trying to merge these two WAVs (L.wav and R.wav) into a single, dual-channel stereo OGG. This is what I'm trying:

```
ffmpeg -i L.wav -i R.wav -c:a libvorbis -q:a 5 \
-filter_complex "[0:a][1:a]amerge" -f ogg out.ogg
```

However, ffmpeg says that:

> Input channel layouts overlap: output layout will be determined by the number of distinct input channels

And that

> 4.0 not supported by Vorbis: output stream will have incorrect channel layout.

So I understand I will only get one audio in only one channel of my output file. So the question is, how can I tell ffmpeg to map channel 0 of L.wav and channel 0 of R.wav into channels 0 and 1 of out.ogg (respectively)? something like this:

```
input #0 [1.0.0.0] → [1.0.0.0] \
                                > output #0 [1.1] 
input #1 [1.0.0.0] → [0.1.0.0] /
```

Answer (score 1):

As you've notices the [`amerge`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amerge) filter combined both stereo inputs into a 4-channel output. The current 4-channel layout:

- `c0` is the left channel from `L.wav`
- `c1` is the right channel from `L.wav`
- `c2` is the left channel from `R.wav`
- `c3` is the right channel from `R.wav`

You can add the [`pan`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pan) filter to mix the desired channels back into a stereo output. As far as I can tell you want `c0` to be the left channel of your output, and `c2` to be the right channel:

```
ffmpeg -i L.wav -i R.wav \
-filter_complex "[0:a][1:a]amerge=inputs=2,pan=stereo|c0=c0|c1=c2[a]" \
-map "[a]" -c:a libvorbis -q:a 5 out.ogg
```

- I usually explicitly add the `input` option to `amerge`. The default is `2`, but I do this in case I use more than 2 inputs; otherwise being forgetful and often lazy I may set it correctly.
- `-f ogg` is superfluous in this case since it will detect the proper format using the output file name.
- See [FFmpeg Wiki: Audio Channel Manipulation](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation) for more examples.